# javax.xml.stream and javax.xml.transform.stream in Java 10

Tags: java, xml, maven, stax, java-10

In Java 8, I've been using these packages:

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
```

Now, in Java 10, they cannot be resolved. What Maven dependency should I include? I don't want to use modules.

[image]

[image]

**Solution:**

Exclude old Maven dependencies stax-api and xml-apis from old libraries.

Comment: They should resolve, unless you've accidentally declared a module. Maybe your IDE added one automatically?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and they don't resolve. Similar problem was with javax.xml.bind, for that I've added Maven dependencies jaxb-*.

Comment: javax.xml.bind is a different problem - it's deprecated and not available by default. java.xml will be available automatically _unless_ you've declared a module (is there a "module-info.java" file in your source path?).

Comment: It would be useful to past in the error message that are you seeing.

Comment: Error is standard class (import) not found. Using default Eclipse settings. I will write details when I get to computer.

Comment: Are you running in an OSGi environment? The packages you mention have been moved into new Java modules and if you're running inside an osgi container, these packages may no longer be available from the framework.

Comment: I've added some images. In which module are my missing packages? If I cannot resolve it with maven dependency, I will include proper package and that's it.

Comment: Module is java.xml (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html). Problem were some Maven dependencies from old libraries - `xml-apis` and `stax-api`. I've excluded them and all is okay.

Comment: This sounds like an Eclipse issue. If you deploy an ancient JAR file with javax.xml.stream.* APIs on the class path then Eclipse should ignore them as javax.xml.stream is exported by the java.xml module.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and deleting old xml dependencies didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `stax-api` dependency from the `pom.xml` file and the issue is gone.